# Redundant fetching on PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to echo the candidate_id where match in my query, but the problem is the candidate_id is redundant. Please help me out of this problem. Thankyou!

```
//The result of $select1:
5
5
6

Note: the rows must be 3 rows that's why the $select2 is must be 3rows only and not a redundant
//The result of $select2:
190220015443 
190220015600 
190220015443 
190220015600 
190220072659 

//Must be the output of $select2:
190220072659 
190220015443 
190220015600 



<?php 
$quarter = '1st';
$year = '2019';
$select1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT MAX(number_votes) FROM inter_department_votes WHERE quarter = '$quarter' AND year_date = '$year' AND number_votes != 0 AND status = '1' GROUP BY dept_id");

    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($select1)) {
        $number_votes1 = $row1['MAX(number_votes)'];

        $select2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT candidate_id, dept_id FROM inter_department_votes WHERE number_votes = '$number_votes1'");

        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($select2)) {
            $candidate_id2 = $row2['candidate_id'];
            echo $candidate_id2 . " " . "<br />";
        }
    }

     ?>
```

PS. I try to group by the query but the result is the same. Please help me out of this problem :-((((

Comment: Did you try to group by `candidate_id` in $select2?

Comment: @M.Hemant yes, I do. But the result is the same.

Comment: @M.Hemant is there any solution with if else statement? or other statement?

Comment: Can you please show the query result of $select1 and $select2. Thanks.

Comment: @pacificskybeachresort how about `SELECT DISTINCT(candidate_id)` ? It will give you distinct values

Comment: @JohnRey I already updated, thank you!

Comment: @pacificskybeachresort is issue resolve already?

Comment: @fmsthird not already :-(

Comment: @pacificskybeachresort check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query using [`SELECT DISTINCT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) function. check this modified code below:

```
<?php 
$quarter = '1st';
$year = '2019';
$select1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT MAX(number_votes) FROM inter_department_votes WHERE quarter = '$quarter' AND year_date = '$year' AND number_votes != 0 AND status = '1' GROUP BY dept_id");

    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($select1)) {
        $number_votes1 = $row1['MAX(number_votes)'];

        $select2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT candidate_id FROM inter_department_votes WHERE number_votes = '".$number_votes1."' GROUP BY candidate_id");

        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($select2)) {
            $candidate_id2 = $row2['candidate_id'];
            echo $candidate_id2 . " " . "<br />";
        }
    }
```

Comment: the result is the same :-((

Comment: @pacificskybeachresort, update the answer please check

Comment: I wrapped the variable `$number_votes1`with double quotes and added group by